# It was to him that

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> **'It was to him'** that Bronn turned with a cursory salute.

This is from "A Game of Thrones".

What does ***It was to him that...*** mean?

Comment: It's an answer to the unspoken question "To whom was it that Bronn turned?"

Comment: Bronn turned to him with a cursory salute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) formed from "Bronn turned to him with a cursory salute".

Comment: Promoting 'him' (and the less usual sentence structure) emphasises [the referent of] 'him' (rather than Bronn / the action).